# Read and sms . What's the difference

Tags: motorola-moto-g

When I get a status update on my texts sent , sometimes it says "read" and sometimes it says "sms". What is the difference between the two.

Comment: What texting app are you using?

Comment: This would vary by app and your settings... "Read" like means the receiver has actually read the message (or at least acknowledged they received it), and "SMS" probably means that the message was sent, but no acknowledgement was returned or requested. Some apps handle their own proprietary messaging that support these features and do SMS 
 messaging (text message) in addition (which may not support some of these features).